# Why do I get <identifier> expected?

Tags: java, identifier

The following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Point;
public class Polygon{
    ArrayList<Point> points;

    //constructs polygon without points

    public Polygon() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }


    /*
     * adds a point to points
     */
    public void addPoint(Point){
        points.add(Point);
    }

    public void draw(){
        for(int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++){
             if(i == 0){
                 points.get(0).draw()
             }else{
                 points.get(i).draw()
                 Line line = new Line(points.get(i-1).getX(), points.get(i-1).getY(), points.get(i).getX(), points.get(i).getY());
                 line.draw();                 
             }
        }

        if(points.size() >= 2){
            Line line = new Line(points.get(-1).getX(), points.get(-1).getY(), points.get(-2).getX(), points.get(-2).getY());
            line.draw();
        }
    }


}
```

gives the exception message:

```
<identifier> expected for public void addPoint(Point)
```

I just cannot figure out why? Those identifiers are normally needed to tell an ArrayList which objects it is going to hold, right?

Comment: See [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) and [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the identifier. `Point` is a type.

```
public void addPoint(Point p){
        points.add(p);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Defination of [Identifier](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/08.html)

> Identifiers are the names of variables, methods, classes, packages and interfaces.
>   Unlike literals they are not the things themselves, just ways of referring to them.
>
> In the HelloWorld program, HelloWorld, String, args, main and println are identifiers.

Here you missed to name addPoint method argument of type `Point`.So you are getting error.
Use this code

```
 public void addPoint(Point p){
     points.add(p);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way in which you have defined the method is wrong. Your method should have type (in your case `Point`) followed by an identifier (say `p`)

```
public void addPoint(Point p){
   points.add(p);
}
```

Check [JLS 8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4), which states

> The formal parameters of a method or constructor, if any, are
>   specified by a list of comma-separated parameter specifiers. Each
>   parameter specifier consists of a **type** (optionally preceded by the
>   final modifier and/or one or more annotations) and an **identifier**
>   (optionally followed by brackets) that specifies the **name of the**
>    **parameter**.

Answer (score 0):

Your "addPoint" method definition is not correct, it does not have any identifier for "Point". It should be written as :

```
public void addPoint(Point pnt){
        points.add(pnt);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method declaration syntax:**

```
public void doSomething(Type variable){

     // logic
}
```

**-** In your case you are missing the `variable` part.

**Proper way:**

```
 public void addPoint(Point point){

        points.add(point);
 }
```